# How to identify unnecessary partitions - dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu, currently using 15.10 with a Win 10 dual boot. I had a number of false attempts at installing the dual boot (started with just windows). I'm not sure what partitions were unnecessarily created in the process of me bumbling through the installation and a few false starts! Any suggestions with how to identify what is and is not being used by both Windows and Ubuntu?

Below should outline what is currently in place. Thanks.

```
NAME    FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda            238.5G            
├─sda1  ntfs    1000M            WINRE_DRV
├─sda2  vfat     260M /boot/efi  SYSTEM_DRV
├─sda3  vfat    1000M            LRS_ESP
├─sda4           128M            
├─sda5  ntfs   190.6G            Windows8_OS
├─sda6  swap     1.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda7  swap     1.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda8  ext4    26.1G /          
├─sda9  ntfs       4G            LENOVO
└─sda10 ntfs    11.7G            PBR_DRV
```

Based on advice from @Rinzwind (thanks). It returned this for me below. Still not clear which is the appropriate to delete, am I missing something?

```
more /etc/fstab|grep swap;
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d89d4722-736b-4d0c-a640-9eefc9f997c3 none            swap    sw              0       0'

'# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=f65db852-9521-487f-bb9f-5a52b98308ae none            swap    sw              0       0'
```

Comment: Bumping this, still looking to determine is sda6 or sda7 can be removed based on the return above.

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions with how to identify what is and is not being used by both Windows and Ubuntu?

Windows is off topic but these are Linux related:

```
├─sda6  swap     1.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda7  swap     1.9G [SWAP]     
├─sda8  ext4    26.1G /
```

That is 1 swap more than needed. If you have a look at `/etc/fstab` it will list what device the swap is on. You can delete the other one.

Example:

```
$ more /etc/fstab|grep swap
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=b3821c31-2db0-48b7-8cab-2e4e0f3a03e4 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Yours will list sda6 or sda7.